# Connect to micro SD through javax.smartcardio

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader

I'm using `javax.smartcardio` to communicate with a smart card reader.
I have also got a micro SD card with a Java Card applet running on it. However `javax.smartcardio` does not recognize the micro SD card as a `Terminal` or `Card`.

`TerminalFactory.getDefault().terminals().list();` only returns the smart card reader. How can I connect with the Applet on the SD card?

Comment: Hi new user and welcome. Please take a look at my edits. You may also want to revisit your previous question, there are some answers there but you haven't reacted on them or accepted one of them.

Comment: Are you going to abandon all your questions like this?

Answer (score 3):

Micro-SD card with integrated Smartcard part are proprietary. You need to use the SDK from the manufacturer of the Micro-SD card.